# Calculating Similarity between two multiset

Tags: similarities, jaccard-similarity

I need to find similarity between two multiset. For example,

$$A = \{a, a, b, c, d\}$$
$$B = \{a, b, b, d\}$$

I know that I can use **Jaccard Index** but it gives same weight for each element. As element **a** has occurred two times in **A** so I want to put extra weight on it.

So, In this case, what's the best algorithm or formula for calculating the similarity?

Comment: Please try first to search `Jaccard similarity` on the site. There are 5 or so potentially helpful or hintful questions.

Comment: Top five.......?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without a clear objective in mind. What application is this for?

Comment: May I know what are the options here?